# How to receive a callback even if you kill the app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app.

I want to continue to receive callback even if I close the app. (For example, Bluetooth connection  or ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)

I know that such a way is a foreground service, but I don't want to use it.

Because if you use the foreground service, you have to make notification essential, but I don't want it.

Is there a good way to get callback even if you shut down the app without using the foreground service?

Comment: There is No Way to get immediate callback if your process is Dead .

Comment: You may use AlarmManger  for callback https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager . You only need to set AlarmManger time repeatedly (eg..delay=20sec )  and pass your class using pendingIntent.

Comment: @Himanshu Sharma If you use the alarm manager repeatedly every 20 seconds, won't the battery consumption increase?

Comment: @SWC no, its uses very minimal battery

Comment: @Himanshu Sharma Is there any simple example of the answer you mentioned?

Comment: check this https://www.py4u.net/discuss/622826